# Subtle differences in data calcuations from array vs list

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

As you can see in the code below, I calculate variance for data in the 'open' column two different ways. The only difference being that in the second version I grab the values rather than the column containing values. Why would this lead to different variance calculations?

```py
apple_prices = pd.read_csv('apple_prices.csv')

print(apple_prices['open'].values.var())
#prints 102.22564310059172

print(apple_prices['open'].var())
#prints 103.82291877403847
```

Comment: Pandas and numpy have different default values for degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference is because that `pandas.Series.var` has a default `ddof` (delta degrees of freedom) of 1, and `numpy.ndarray.var` has a default `ddof` of 0. Manually setting this produces the same result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

x = pd.Series(np.random.rand(100))

print(x.var(ddof=1))
# 0.08395738934787107


print(x.values.var(ddof=1))
# 0.08395738934787107
```

See the documentation at:
[pandas.Series.var](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.var.html)
[numpy.var](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html#numpy.var)